# Cookies not working with an AJAX call from jQuery to Django

Tags: django, cookies, django-voting

I have a Django site using a 5-star rating system for voting (I use [django-ratings](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings)) and I would like to store the votings of the users with AJAX calls.

On the client side I have a JavaScript function sending a GET request to a URL:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Load was performed.');
    }
});
```

On the server side I have code setting the cookie:

```
def vote(request, slug, rating):

    # Some irrelevant code...
    response = HttpResponse('Vote changed.')
    response.set_cookie('vote', 123456)
    return response
```

The problem is that the cookie is never set in the browser.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are sure that your problem is about Cross-site request forgery protection? most ajax requests rejected django by that. Don't you have any error messages?