# Setting cookies in an AJAX call with Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, setcookie

I have a Django site and I am trying to set a cookie in a response from an AJAX call. I made the question more general since nowbody was answering [Cookies not working with an AJAX call from jQuery to Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378340/cookies-not-working-with-an-ajax-call-from-jquery-to-django)

On the client side I have a JavaScript function sending a GET request to a URL:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Load was performed.');
    }
});
```

On the server side I have code setting the cookie:

```
def vote(request, slug, rating):

    # Some irrelevant code...
    response = HttpResponse('Vote changed.')
    response.set_cookie('vote', 123456)
    return response
```

I get the response in the jQuery code, but the problem is that the cookie is never set in the browser.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating the cookie specifying an expiry date, something like the below:

```
var max_age = 14*24*60*60 # two weeks
expires = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=max_age), "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S GMT")

response.set_cookie('vote', 123456, max_age=max_age, expires=expires)
```

Apologies if the example is a little off - it's been a while since I worked with Django and had to google the cookie/date syntax.